# PHP DOM $xpath->query Get The Raw HTML as an Output

Tags: php

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('//div[@class="container jgQsqn"]');
if($items->length > 0){
foreach ($items as $item) {
echo $item->nodeValue;
}
}
```

Problem:

It's providing me all the nodeValue but I need the HTML codes along with it. Here's the workaround code I've created:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="container jgQsqn"]');
if($div->length > 0){
$div = $div->item(0);
$result = $dom->saveXML($div);
}
```

Problem With This Code: The class **container jgQsqn** is used in multiple div. I need to fetch the content of all of them. But this code only outputs the content from the first Division and I'm confused where I can use the loop to access all of them.

Comment: `$xpath->query` returns a list of divs, so you should be able to use the same pattern from your first example, like `$divs = $xpath->query(...) ... foreach ($divs as $div) { $result = $dom->saveXML($div) }` Have you tried that?

Comment: lemme try that, thanks!